# Checking whether a number is a power of 10

Tags: java

Is there a better way to check whether a number is a power of 10? This is what I've implemented:

```
    public class PowersOfTen {

    public static boolean isPowerOfTen(long input) {

        if (input % 10 != 0 || input == 0) {
            return false;
        }

        if (input == 10) {
            return true;
        }

        return isPowerOfTen(input/10);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println("1000: " + isPowerOfTen(1000));
        System.out.println("4: " + isPowerOfTen(4));
        System.out.println("0: " + isPowerOfTen(0));
        System.out.println("10: " + isPowerOfTen(10));
        System.out.println("100: " + isPowerOfTen(100));
    }
}
```

Comment: Obviously this won't work for negative powers of 10 at the moment - is that a requirement?

Comment: @TomFenech If the input is an integer, it can't be a negative power of 10.  Unless you mean something like -1000, which isn't power of 10.

Comment: @ErickWong that's one of the reasons I asked; I was referring to numbers like 0.1, which would obviously require a different implementation.

Comment: @TomFenech that opens a massive can of worms. Remember floating point types can't exactly represent negative powers of 10 either.

Comment: @Peter I know :) to be honest I'm not sure how I'd go about implementing it myself! Nevertheless I thought it was worth clarifying whether it was a requirement. I guess not!

Comment: `1` is a power of 10 though, since 10 to the power of 0 is 1. This function returns false for 1.

Comment: **Moderator's note to reviewers:** Yes, there are many different ways to solve this problem. However, this being Code Review, answers must have some bearing on the code in the question. If you present an independent solution, you also need to include some justification.

Comment: You asked if there is a better way - define better, please. Do you mean, more performant, easier to read, mathematically more elegant? If you are asking about "better way" in terms of performance, look at the code in context. Is there any pattern to the numbers you are testing? You may be able to take advantage of that by, for instance, skipping all odd numbers except 1 (just look at the LSB) before you even start testing. But for some data patterns, such optimizations may make performance worse.

Comment: If this were [tag:c] (with compiler builtins), you'd be able to use [this `digits()` function](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9721570/2113226).  `n` is a power of 10 if `digits(n) > digits(n - 1)`.  I have no idea if Java can do anything like a CPU instruction `__builtin_clz()` though.

Comment: See also [this similar question on SO][https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2551657/c-how-can-i-test-if-a-number-is-power-of-ten]

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Recursing seems pretty heavy for this. You can use much the same logic but with a simple loop:

```
while (input >= 10 && input % 10 == 0) 
  input /= 10;
return input == 1;
```

This checks to make sure the input is at least 10 (since any integers below that, including zero and negative values, can't be powers of 10) and also a multiple of 10 (as all powers of 10 greater than 1 obviously are). It does the simpler comparison first as a small micro-optimization; the short-circuit evaluation will avoid performing an unnecessary division to compute an unneeded modulus.

If both conditions are met it does an integer division by 10 and repeats the process. For any power of 10, this will terminate with the value 1; if 1 itself is passed in, it will do so without ever executing the body of the `while` loop.

Comment: Making it `while (input > 9 ...` instead avoids some superfluous extra calculations for inputs of 1 through 9 (and 10^x multiples of those as well).

Comment: @JeffY How will it handle negative powers of 10? For inputs like 0.1 or 0.01 etc.

Comment: See: `long input`.

Comment: @ParasDPain the input is a `long`, which is an integral type.  Fractional values are not possible.

Comment: I see, the requirements.

Answer (score 41):

You could also just list them out as there aren't that many in range of the long datatype.

Advantages over the code in the OP is that it is simple, clear, and correct.

Disadvantages are that some might consider it verbose. Additionally a (potential) micro optimisation might be to break the comparisons up into smaller groups and perform a binary search to reduce the number of comparisons in the case that a non power of 10 is passed.

```
public static boolean isPowerOfTen(long input) {
  return 
    input == 1L
  || input == 10L
  || input == 100L
  || input == 1000L
  || input == 10000L
  || input == 100000L
  || input == 1000000L
  || input == 10000000L
  || input == 100000000L
  || input == 1000000000L
  || input == 10000000000L
  || input == 100000000000L
  || input == 1000000000000L
  || input == 10000000000000L
  || input == 100000000000000L
  || input == 1000000000000000L
  || input == 10000000000000000L
  || input == 100000000000000000L
  || input == 1000000000000000000L;
}
```

Comment: Indeed, or put them in a static (or otherwise, if conciseness is desirable) set which you can test membership of.

Comment: **[Sorting Hat version.](https://pastebin.com/raw/9ku0zE0Z)**

Comment: Also a bit slow because all ors will be making the CPU have to branch many times but.. wait this is Java anyway so it's gonna be slow no matter what.

Comment: I don't think binary search would improve the speed; you would get branch prediction misses all over the place. If you get a single branch prediction wrong, the linear check you have is probably faster.

Comment: @FilipHaglund - Yes. It would need to be tested whether it helps or hinders - and even if it did help unless this is a critical path in the code the loss of clarity probably wouldn't compensate anyway.

Comment: Or you could throw some simd instructions in there to maybe save a clock cycle or two :D

Comment: This answer is the base for this [code-golf question](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/70896/48943)

Answer (score 33):

I consider your code to be incorrect, because I expect `isPowerOfTen(1)` to be `true`.

Comment: You're right, good pick up.

Comment: Just change `if (input == 10)` for `if (input == 1)` and put that `if` block first.

Comment: So "Is there a better way to check whether a number is a power of 10? "

Comment: @MartinSmith this is more of a valid review point than simply rewriting the solution and saying "here you go"

Answer (score 14):

#### Mathematical alternative

There's [`Math.log10()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#log10-double-):

```
public static boolean isPowerOfTen(long value) {
    // updated answer - check for precision in if statement
    if (value >= 1e14) {
        try {
            return isPowerOfTen(BigDecimal.valueOf(value)
                                    .divide(BigDecimal.valueOf(1e14)).longValueExact());
        } catch (ArithmeticException e) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    double power = Math.log10(value);
    return Double.isFinite(power) && Math.round(power) == power;
}
```

***Take care about precision***, as mentioned in [@ErickWong](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/117203/checking-whether-a-number-is-a-power-of-10/117214?noredirect=1#comment217987_117214)'s comment. I've updated my answer above to handle values above `1e14`, which seems to be the point where precision is lost.

#### Unit testing

Your simple tests in `main()` should be converted into the form of a [unit test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_testing). For example, using [TestNG](http://testng.org/doc/index.html):

```
public void testPowerOfTen() {
    assertTrue(isPowerOfTen(1)); // 10^0, as mentioned by @200_success
    assertTrue(isPowerOfTen(1000));
    assertFalse(isPowerOfTen(4));
    assertFalse(isPowerOfTen(0));
    assertTrue(isPowerOfTen(10));
    assertTrue(isPowerOfTen(100));
}
```

Comment: Have you tested this against precision issues?  The log10 of 10^18+1 is going to be very close to 18, likely closer than can be represented faithfully in double precision.

Comment: @ErickWong entirely valid point. :) Have updated my answer.

Comment: I don't like this solution since 1) Assuring myself that it's correct is too hard. Floating point rounding is tricky. 2) The use of an exception as part of the core logic.

Comment: @CodesInChaos personally, I think the main problem with my approach starts with the `if (value >= 14)`. If that can be handwaved away, I reckon the original approach is OK-ish. Hence the 'take care about precision' emphasis... ;)

Comment: @h.j.k. The part you would like to handwave away is essential to the correctness of the method.  Fundamentally the problem is shoehorning a function like log10 whose correctness is only approximate into a problem that requires exactness.

Comment: This seems horribly inefficient... :c

Answer (score 9):

In the same vein as Martin Smith's answer, you could store all powers of 10 in order in an array and then do a binary search:

```
private static final long[] powersOf10 = new long[] {
    1L, 10L, 100L, 1000L, 10000L, 100000L, 1000000L, 10000000L,
    100000000L, 1000000000L, 10000000000L, 100000000000L,
    1000000000000L, 10000000000000L, 100000000000000L, 1000000000000000L,
    10000000000000000L, 100000000000000000L, 1000000000000000000L
};

static boolean isPowerOfTen(long input) {
    return Arrays.binarySearch(powersOf10, input) >= 0;
}
```

Note: this method is *far* less efficient than Martin's (about 2.5x as slow on my computer) for this small data set but it scales much better to large data sets.

On the other hand, if you need extreme speed then this algorithm, based on 5gon12eder's comment, might be worth using. It switches on the lower bits of the input (you can't switch on a long) and if it gets a hit, it performs a linear search.

```
static boolean isPowerOfTen(long input) {
    switch ((int)input) {
        case (int)1L:
        case (int)10L:
        case (int)100L:
        case (int)1000L:
        case (int)10000L:
        case (int)100000L:
        case (int)1000000L:
        case (int)10000000L:
        case (int)100000000L:
        case (int)1000000000L:
        case (int)10000000000L:
        case (int)100000000000L:
        case (int)1000000000000L:
        case (int)10000000000000L:
        case (int)100000000000000L:
        case (int)1000000000000000L:
        case (int)10000000000000000L:
        case (int)100000000000000000L:
        case (int)1000000000000000000L:
            return linearSearch(input);
        default:
            return false;
    }
}

// from Martin Smith's answer:
private static boolean linearSearch(long input) {
    return
        input == 1L
            || input == 10L
            || input == 100L
            || input == 1000L
            || input == 10000L
            || input == 100000L
            || input == 1000000L
            || input == 10000000L
            || input == 100000000L
            || input == 1000000000L
            || input == 10000000000L
            || input == 100000000000L
            || input == 1000000000000L
            || input == 10000000000000L
            || input == 100000000000000L
            || input == 1000000000000000L
            || input == 10000000000000000L
            || input == 100000000000000000L
            || input == 1000000000000000000L;
}
```

Benchmark computing on first billion positive ints:

- linear search (Martin Smith): 2970 ms
- binary search: 6908 ms
- switch on hash then linear search: 1519 ms

Comment: I think a `switch` statement would be the fastest (and most readable?) solution here.

Comment: @5gon12eder Java doesn't support switching on longs.

Comment: Ups, I forgot that… You could “hash” the bits of a `long` into an `int` and `switch` over that but It would be less obvious.

Comment: @5gon12eder If you hash, you would get false positives. You could hash and then if you get a match, run an exact algorithm. That would be much faster and I will update this answer accordingly.

Comment: Well, the idea actually was to resolve hash collisions with `if`s in the respective `case`s. But your version looks good too and is harder to get wrong.

Comment: @5gon12eder Strangely, I benchmarked code where each case has a statement `return input == [exact value]` and it's much slower (4342 ms). So it seems that if many switch cases drop to the same block, the code can be optimized more aggressively than if each case has a separate block. I'm not sure why.

Comment: Why do you need to carry out a the `linearSearch` _after_ the `switch`? Surely, if you fall through you already know that the value is in the set of multiple of `10` - this seems superfluous. Also, the benchmarks, unless done with Caliper or JMH are largely meaningless.

Comment: @BoristheSpider Because we compare (int)input to (int)value, which means we could get false positives. As for the benchmarks, I run the operation many times before timing to warm it up and use the result of the computation in a way that can't be optimized out. But feel free to run with another tool - all the code is here.

Comment: @Solomonoff'sSecret why don't count the number of trailing zeros (i.e. `numberOfTrailingZeros`) and use it as an index to the array?

Comment: @FranMowinckel I assume you mean # of trailing zeros in base 10 (unlike `Long.numberOfTrailingZeros`, which is in binary). If you compute that then you have already basically solved the problem with a separate algorithm.

Comment: @Solomonoff'sSecret No, I mean the number of trailing zeros in binary. 10=2*5 so the number of zeros in binary must be the same as the number of decimal zeros. But I don't know how efficient is that method.

Comment: @FranMowinckel You're right, that's a nice enhancement. I get 880 ms, almost twice as fast as the switch version (and the code is much nicer too)! My implementation is `return powersOf10[Long.numberOfTrailingZeros(input)] == input;` with the array right-padded to size 65 with -1. You might want to write that up as a separate answer.

Comment: @FranMowinckel Apologies, the benchmark was flawed. I corrected it (it's now comparable to the other ones in my post) and now I get 2353 ms. But perhaps it could be further optimized.

Comment: What about a lookup with a `Map<Long, Boolean>`?

Comment: @Supuhstar That's almost certainly slower than binary search or switch until your table gets quite large.

Answer (score 3):

### Iterative version

This suggestion is similar to @200_success's answer. This can be contracted into a for-loop if you are into that sort of thing :). Points of interest:

- No recursion. Recursion makes for elegant code but those extra function calls compared to an iterative function sometimes comes at a significant performance penalty.
- Using multiplication instead of division (which is supposed to be faster but I'm no authority on that)
- No special handling of 0, 1 or negative `input` numbers. Base needs checking though.
- Other bases than 10 can be used.

Java:

```
public static boolean isPowerOf(long input, long base) {
    if (base < 2) throw new IllegalArgumentException("base must be 2 or larger");
    //find the biggest number that is safe to multiply base with without getting integer oveflow
    long safeMultiplier = Long.MAX_VALUE / base;
    long x = 1;
    while (x < input && x <= safeMultiplier) {
        x *= base;
    }
    return x == input;
}
```

### BigInteger version

Because sometimes Long is just not long enough :)

```
public static boolean isPowerOf(BigInteger input, BigInteger base) {
    if (base.compareTo(BigInteger.ONE) != 1) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("base must be 2 or larger");
    }
    BigInteger x = BigInteger.ONE;
    int comparison;
    while ((comparison = x.compareTo(input)) == -1) {
        x = x.multiply(base);
    }
    return comparison == 0;
}
```

### Recursive version

Recursive version still using multiplication instead of division. Putting the recursive call last in the function (like you also did) is a nod towards languages that can perform tail call optimization (http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?TailCallOptimization & https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_call). I don't think Java does that however.

```
public static boolean recursiveIsPowerOf(long input, long base) {
    if (base < 2) throw new IllegalArgumentException("base must be 2 or larger");
    //find the biggest number that is safe to multiply base with without getting integer oveflow
    long safeMultiplier = Long.MAX_VALUE / base;
    if (safeMultiplier < base)
        return input == base;

    return recursiveIsPowerOf(input, base, 1);
}

private static boolean recursiveIsPowerOf(long input, long base, long x) {
    return (x >= input || x < 0) ? x == input : recursiveIsPowerOf(input, base, x * base);
}
```

Edit(s):

- Added integer overflow check as per @ErickWong's suggestion
- Added check for valid base (> 1)
- Added BigInteger version
- Fixed faulty overflow checks

Comment: I think the iterative version will go into an infinite loop if the input is too large relative to MAX_INT/base.  Have you tested this on an input that is approximately 2/3 times MAX_INT?

Comment: @ErickWong Wong You are right. As java seem to silently wrap around on integer overflow it will go into an infinite loop. Good catch. I added an overflow check. I love that my answer to a code review post just got reviewed. :)

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately the overflow check isn't sufficient.  It's fine when base == 2 but for larger bases it is entirely possible for 10*x to overflow to a positive value.  A safer way to check for overflow is to spend a single divide outside the for loop to find the maximum value that it's ok to multiply base by.

Answer (score 3):

This is for fun, but what about this very basic solution?:

```
String.valueOf(x).matches("^10*$")
```

It should also work for `long` and `BigDecimal`'s using `toPlainString()`.

BTW I know that it's not high performance :P.

Also as a curiosity, any power of 10 in binary representation ends with itself:

```
1 -> b'1'
10 -> b'x10'
100 -> b'x100'
1000 -> b'x1000'
...
```

(where x is a sequence of '1' and '0')

Comment: @WashingtonGuedes shame on me! thanks! what a silly mistake

Comment: Anyways +1.. I'd do this too without thinking two times... I personally like to _extrapolate_ the regex's purpose

Answer (score 2):

No divisions, no moduli, no recursion? Here we go:

```
public static boolean power10(int n) {
    int max_power10 = 100000; //whatever you can accept given your type
    int i = 1;
    while ( i != n && i != max_power10) i *= 10;   
    return i == n;
}
```

---

Improvement:

```
public static boolean power10(int n) {
    int max_power10 = 100000; //whatever you can accept given your type
    if (n > max_power10 ) return false;
    int i = 1;
    while (i < n) i *= 10;   
    return i == n;
}
```

Comment: why not a simple `while ( i < n)`?

Comment: @FranMowinckel because it may cause overflow. Think about the case in which n is the maximum `int` value.

Comment: C'mon, that's just a limit case that you can check before (i.e. `if (n > max_power10) return false`)

Answer (score 1):

IMO it would be cleaner as:

```
public static boolean isPowerOfTen(long input) {
    if (input <= 0 ) {
        // powers of 10 can't be 0 or negative
        return false;
    }

    // don't have to worry about negative powers since long input
    // doesn't hold fractions
    for (int pow = 0; pow <= Math.log10(Long.MAX_VALUE); ++pow) {
        if (input == (long)Math.pow(10, pow)) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Math.log10(Long.MAX_VALUE) will yield the maximum power of 10 that will fit into a long, the floor of which is (truncated by implicit conversion to) 18.

From here we can also easily make the method generic by replacing references to 10 and Math.log10. **Java doesn't have a Math.logb method, but recall: logb(x) = logc(x) / logc(b).** So logb(Long.MAX_VALUE) = Math.log(Long.MAX_VALUE) / Math.log(b):

```
public static boolean isPowerOf(long input, int base) {
    if (input <= 0 ) {
        return false;
    }

    for (int pow = 0; pow <= Math.log(Long.MAX_VALUE) / Math.log(base); ++pow) {
        if (input == Math.floor(Math.pow(base, pow))) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

**But we can also eliminate the loop with a little math to find the power directly and check if it is an integer:**

```
public static boolean isPowerOf(long input, int base) {
    if (input == 0) {
        return false;
    }

    // use Math.abs since if the argument is NaN or less than zero to Math.log, 
    // then the result is NaN. This makes it work for negative inputs and bases
    Double power = Math.log(Math.abs(input)) / Math.log(Math.abs(base));

    // power might have lost precision, so I'm trying floor and ceiling. These are integers so if either yields the input, return true
    return (input == (long)Math.pow(base, Math.floor(power)) ||
            input == (long)Math.pow(base,  Math.ceil(power)));
}
```

Comment: 1) I'd avoid using floating point for integer problem, that makes reasoning about it far too difficult. Even if it happens to be correct, it requires far too much thinking to make sure it's correct. 2) Your code is clearly wrong, since `Math.pow` returns a `double` which can't represent every valid `long`.

Comment: 3) You could use [`BigInteger.pow`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#pow%28int%29) instead of `math.pow`. 4) rounding the power to an integer would be simpler than testing both `floor` and `ceil`.

Answer (score 1):

Iteration would be more efficient than recursion.

Also `input == 1` should count as a power of `10`.

```
public static boolean isPowerOfTen(long input) {
    while (input > 1) {
        if (input % 10 != 0)
            return false;
        input = input / 10;
    }

    if (input == 1) {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Even shorter version (suggested by Landei – thanks!):

```
public static boolean isPowerOfTen(long input) {
    while (input > 1) {
        if (input % 10 != 0)
            return false;
        input /= 10;
    }

    return input == 1;
}
```

Comment: I'm always baffled when I see code like this. Why the last `if`? Why not simply `return input == 1`?

Comment: @Landei Well, me too. But I've seen code like this so many times here, that I started to believe this is a preferred style in Java programmers community. Corrected now.

Comment: @Landei it's more explicit in its intent

Comment: @Supuhstar Your brain needs to process four lines instead of one, there is branching and the method has two exit points instead of one. That might be "more explicit", but it is clearly less comprehensible.

Comment: @Landei four simpler lines that read more naturally in English than one terse line that reads more mathematically. Anyway, this is not the place for this. If you want to continue this discussion, feel free to email me at Supuhstar0@gmail.com

Answer (score 0):

Here is one if we would want to avoid CPU-branching, which would be nice in compiled languages like C or C++ for CPUs which have broad instruction pipelines. It counts all non-zeros and ones in base 10.

The idea is: if and only if there are no larger-than-ones and exactly one 1, then we have a power of 10.

```
int ispow10(int aInput){
  int lCntO = 0, lCnt1 = 0, lTmp = 0, i = 0;
  for( i=0 ;i < 10; i++, aInput /= 10 ){
    lTmp = aInput % 10;
    lCntO += (lTmp > 1);
    lCnt1 += (lTmp == 1);
  }
return (lCntO == 0)&(lCnt1==1);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I know it's possibly not the best option, but I always find interesting to approach math-y simple problems from a human perspective and no one suggested the approach yet of, in this case, looking at how the number is written:

```
boolean isPowerOfTen(int n) {
    char[] digits = (n+"").toCharArray();
    if (digits[0] != '1') return false;
    for (int i = 1; i<digits.length; i++) {
      if (digits[i] != '0') return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

You can easily extend it for negative powers (0.000001) and it's arguably much easier to read and short than other methods, though it has a worse performance.